# Losing material when prefab is created

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a game object with these properties:

[image]

So when I create the prefab, right after the creation, on the prefab the material is lost. The mesh renderer doesn't contain any material.

What is the problem? The other properties are set as default.

UPDATE:
Not only the material it's lost, but also the Mesh Filter

Comment: Delete the prefab, reimport the sprite and then try re-creating the prefab. Alternatively, just delete the Sprite altogether from the project, reimport and try again. There's nothing much to be gleaned from the screenshot, except maybe there's something wonky going on in Unity's PrefabUtility class (there shouldn't be, normally). You could also try creating the prefab through script and see if the same thing happens then.

Comment: I don't have any sprite, it's the default material that it's called Sprites/Default